# jQuery selector + slideUp + slideDown with option select not working correctly

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

please take a look at this fiddle link : http://jsfiddle.net/NQqbE/1/

here is my jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#B h4').mouseover(function(){
        $('#C').slideDown();
    });

    $('#C').mouseleave(function(){
        $('#C').slideUp();
    }); 
});
```

I already manage to slideDown "div#C" with a click from "div#B h4"
but the problem is when I hover on my select option element inside div#C value number 2-5 the div#C slideUp again, maybe because my mouse leave the div.

so my question: is there anyway to select those option select that go outside the div#C and the jquery still read it as inside div#C so the mouseleave function dont run

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 0):

if you seperate C and B, it works

```
<div id="A">
    <div id="B">
        <h4>Show Menu</h4>
    </div>
    <div id="C">
        <p>This is a paragraph</p>
        <select>
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
            <option>4</option>
            <option>5</option>
        </select>
    </div>        
</div>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#B').mouseenter(function(){
        $('#C').slideDown();
    });

    $('#C').mouseleave(function(){
        $('#C').slideUp();
    });

});
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NQqbE/2/

Comment: hey scones thanks for the reply but my problem is when user selected those select options that go outside the div#C *question updated*